# Automated Weblogic Service Testing using Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, weblogic

What I am looking for is a "best practices" description or example by which testing can be automated for components that are deployed to a Weblogic server.

I am not expecting anyone to present a step by step solution to this problem.
I am looking for a **resource** (book, manual, website, etc.) that can describe a path to this integration and testing goal.

The situation is that we have a pair of (*Maven*) Project deployments (*in Eclipse*) which are managed/reviewed/maintained through: **Git, Stash, and Jenkins**.

The first component is providing Web Services (*RESTful* services as well as *Stateful* and *Stateless* services). It is connected to the second component. The second component exposes *Stateless* and *RESTful* services that provide access services (CRUD: Create Read Update Delete) to an **Oracle SQL Database**.

Currently, the **Jenkins** Service is testing the Client UI through **Jasmine** Zzzzz.spec.js tests. This is all well and good for the "front-end hipsters", but not helpful for the **Java** service component developers.

What I would like to do is to be able to write (?**JUnit**?) tests to evaluate Service component operations that can be automatically executed by **Jenkins** continuous integration components. What I would like to avoid doing is mocking up everything to the point that the tests become trivial and pointless.

What needs to happen is:

1. Developer completes a Work Product (**JIRA** Task) to add functionality to a Service hosted by a **Weblogic Server**.

2. Work Product contains a Test (?**JUnit**?).

3. Work Product (including test) is pushed by **Git** to **Stash**.

4. Work Product Test is added to Integration Tests.

5. **Stash** and **Jenkins** execute and evaluate Work Product **JUnit** Test as part of [**Integration Testing**].

**Integration Testing** will:

1. Start a (configured) **Weblogic** Server (if one is not already started).

2. Compile and Publish Deployment containing Work Product.

3. Deployment will connect to a Configured **Datasource**.

4. Start [**Work Product JUnit Test**].

**Work Product JUnit Test** will:

1. Connect and authenticate to **Weblogic** Service Deployment.

2. Call tested Service methods.

3. Evaluate test results

Yes, that is a tall order with a hive full of buzzwords. However, I am having difficulty finding a worthwhile resource that isn't trying to direct me to mock up the very components that I am trying to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is a pretty standard CI setup; the sort of thing that is notable via its *absence* rather than its existence.

In that vein, it's probably appropriate for you and your team to read up on the fundamentals.

- [Continuous Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336380) (Fowler series)
- [Continuous Delivery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912) (Fowler series)
- [The DevOps Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1942788002)

then if you really want, you can pick up books on the specifics of Jenkins:

- [Jenkins: the definitive guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449305350) (oreilly)
- [Jenkins CI Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849517401)

Comment: That was the answer that I was hoping not to get...
To paraphrase:  I am endeavoring, ... to construct a _italic_ Continuous Testing, Integration Environment _italic_ using stone knives and bearskins.
Thank you for the resources.

Comment: There's resources about *why* to do CI, and there's resources on *how*, e.g. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch06s03.html

I don't know what else to tell you.